# Функция возвращает undefined и прерывает таймер (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Есть следующий код: раз в 500 мс происходит вывод случайного числа. Число не должно повторяться. Сделала проверку повтора в функции color() и если произошел повтор, вызвать функцию снова.

**Проблема** в том, что функция color() возвращает undefined после того, как встретила повтор в массиве already и прерывает таймер, не выводя все числа.

```js
let already = [];
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function random() {
  return A[Math.floor(Math.random() * A.length)];
}

function color() {
  let square = random();
  if (already.length >= A.length) {
    return false;
  }
  if (already.indexOf(square) === -1) {
    already.push(square);
    console.log(square);
    return true;
  }
  color();
}

(function tick() {
  let t = setTimeout(function() {
    let f = color();
    if (!f) {
      clearTimeout(t);
    } else {
      tick();
    }
  }, 500);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function color() {
  let square = random();
  if (already.length >= A.length) {
    return false;
  }
  if (already.indexOf(square) === -1) {
    already.push(square);
    console.log(square);
    return true;
  }
  return color(); // !!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, ошибка в том, что в месте рекурсивного вызова не возвращается значение. Вместо `color();` нужно `return color();`

Answer (score 1):

Как я поняла проблема была в следующем:

1. Вызывается функция tick()
2. Вызывается функция color() из функции tick()
3. Не попадая ни в одно из условий, вызывается функция color() **из функции color()** и возвращает какой-то результат в функцию color(), из которой была вызвана.
4. Функция color(), которая была вызвана из функции tick(), дальнейших инструкций не имеет и возвращает undefined.